# Creating a KafkaSpout with a consumer group id

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I've been trying a lot since some time to understand on how to create a group of kafkaspouts subscribing to a single topic. I have found some sources citing the id in spoutconfig can be used as group id. My main problem is how do I know if the spouts created act as a group. I also wonder if paralellism_hint in `setSpout()` is the one creating a group of paralellism_hint number of spouts. Please enlighten me.

My code is something like this

```
private KafkaSpout buildKafkaSpout(String zkTopic, String zkRoot, String groupId) {

        String zkConnString = "localhost:2181";
        BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(zkConnString);
        SpoutConfig kafkaSpoutConfig = new SpoutConfig (hosts, zkTopic,zkRoot, groupId );
        kafkaSpoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
        KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaSpoutConfig);
        return kafkaSpout;
    }

private void buildTopologyForGroupOne(TopologyBuilder builder ) {

        String zkTopic = "topic1";
        String zkRoot = "/topic1";
        String groupId = "group1";
        List<String> zkSpoutIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        zkSpoutIds.add("word_count-spout");
        zkSpoutIds.add("total_word_count-spout");

        for(String spoutId:zkSpoutIds ){
            KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = buildKafkaSpout(zkTopic, zkRoot, groupId);
            builder.setSpout(spoutId.concat("_"+groupId), kafkaSpout,2);
        }
        builder.setBolt("word_split-bolt_group_1",new SplitBolt()).shuffleGrouping("word_count-spout"+"_"+groupId);
        builder.setBolt("split_count-bolt_group_1",new CountBolt()).shuffleGrouping("word_split-bolt_group_1");
        builder.setBolt("total_word_count-bolt_group_1",new TotalWordCountBolt()).shuffleGrouping("total_word_count-spout"+"_"+groupId);

    }
```

Now how do I know if the two spouts I created(word_count-spout,total_word_count-spout) act as a group. By acting as a group I mean if a new spout is created will the zookeeper rearrange the partitions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Finally found a source. A KafkaSpout with a consumer id can be created using  the new version of storm apache-storm-1.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

storm-kafka employes SimpleConsumer instead of the high-level consumer API, so group.id is not important since it is for high-level consumer which uses this setting to implement high availability and failover.

So back to your question, I prefer to think something wrong will happen for your code in the runtime since two consumer instances will contend for the same zk path lock.

Comment: My intention is using a group id for kafkaSpout.Did you mean to say it is not possible?

Comment: For performance consideration, you can set the worker number/ executor number / task number in terms of Storm to achieve better throughput.

Setting group.id has no impact to the KafkaSpout. Besides that should be client id which tells ZK where to store the offset, not the group id you think.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.My aim is enabling one spouts output to be consumed by multiple bolts, which can be done.But, the problem in such implementation is that if one bolt fails to ack the tuple, the tuple is replayed to every other bolt also by the spout.I want to avoid this.I would be very thankful if you can you suggest me a way out.I have been trying using stream names to find a solution.Haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: I remember Storm only replays the stream where there exists a failed tuple which cannot be acknowledged. And you might declare multiple streams to have different bolts subscribe different stream. In doing so might you avoid the situation you worry about.

Comment: I've been trying the same. But the problem is even though the bolts ack the spout is unable to ack and the messages are continously replayed, because of which i'm unable to test if one bolt fails what happens.And also I'm unable to create a spout which reads from topics as the KafkaSpout does.Any help in this direction please.

Comment: I have succesfully tested the functionality of streams and found that even if one bolt fails spout emitts data to all the streams and this way all bolts are executed again. In my spout in the nexttuple() my logic is : if(messageId ==0||messageFailureCount.containsKey(0) ){
    collector.emit("streamA",new Values(transactionMessage),0);
    } if(transactionId==1||transactionFailureCount.containsKey(1)){
    collector.emit("streamB",new Values(message),1);
    } .   If you can point out a source code contradicting this I would be very thankful. Thanks for all the patience :)

Comment: It sort of  deviated from your original post a little bit. In my understanding, you have to provide a messageId when emitting a tuple if you want to do this, and write your logic code in fail method to replay this tuple.